# Find the minimum value in a Pandas dataframe and add a label on new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, min

What improvements can I make to my python pandas code to make it more efficient? For my case, I have this dataframe

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'PersonID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                           'Name': ["Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Don", "Don", "Don", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"],
                           'Label': ["REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL"],
                           'RuleID': [55, 55, 55, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10],
                           'RuleNumber': [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 234, 567, 999]})
```

Which gives this result:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   PersonID Name Label  RuleID  RuleNumber
0         1  Jan   REL      55          3
1         1  Jan   REL      55          4
2         1  Jan   REL      55          5
3         2  Don   REL       3          1
4         2  Don   REL       3          2
5         2  Don   REL       3          3
6         3  Joe   REL      10        234
7         3  Joe   REL      10        567
8         3  Joe   REL      10        999
```

What I need to accomplished here is to update the fields under the Label column to MAIN for the lowest rule value associated with each Rule ID that is applied to a Person ID and Name. Therefore, the results need to look like this:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   PersonID Name Label  RuleID  RuleNumber
0         1  Jan  MAIN      55           3
1         1  Jan   REL      55           4
2         1  Jan   REL      55           5
3         2  Don  MAIN       3           1
4         2  Don   REL       3           2
5         2  Don   REL       3           3
6         3  Joe  MAIN      10         234
7         3  Joe   REL      10         567
8         3  Joe   REL      10         999
```

This is the code that I wrote to accomplish this:

```
In [4]:

df['Label'] = np.where(
        df['RuleNumber'] ==
        df.groupby(['PersonID', 'Name', 'RuleID'])['RuleNumber'].transform('min'),
        "MAIN", df.Label)
```

Is there a better way to update the values under the Label column? I feel like I'm brute forcing my way through and this may not be the most efficient way to do this.

I used the following SO threads to arrive at my result:

[Replace column values within a groupby and condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142757/replace-column-values-within-a-groupby-and-condition)

[Replace values within a groupby based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418372/replace-values-within-a-groupby-based-on-multiple-conditions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html

[Using Pandas to Find Minimum Values of Grouped Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450963/using-pandas-to-find-minimum-values-of-grouped-rows)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you can filter by the grouped `idxmin` regardless of sorted order and update `RuleNumber` based on that. You can use `loc`, `np.where`, `mask`, or `where` as follows:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['PersonID', 'Name', 'RuleID'])['RuleNumber'].idxmin(), 'Label'] = 'MAIN'
```

OR with `np.where` as you were trying:

```
df['Label'] = (np.where((df.index == df.groupby(['PersonID', 'Name', 'RuleID'])
                         ['RuleNumber'].transform('idxmin')), 'MAIN', 'REL'))
df
Out[1]: 
   PersonID Name Label  RuleID  RuleNumber
0         1  Jan  MAIN      55           3
1         1  Jan   REL      55           4
2         1  Jan   REL      55           5
3         2  Don  MAIN       3           1
4         2  Don   REL       3           2
5         2  Don   REL       3           3
6         3  Joe  MAIN      10         234
7         3  Joe   REL      10         567
8         3  Joe   REL      10         999
```

Using `mask` or its inverse `where` would also work:

```
df['Label'] = (df['Label'].mask((df.index == df.groupby(['PersonID', 'Name', 'RuleID'])
                         ['RuleNumber'].transform('idxmin')), 'MAIN'))
```

OR

```
df['Label'] = (df['Label'].where((df.index != df.groupby(['PersonID', 'Name', 'RuleID'])
                         ['RuleNumber'].transform('idxmin')), 'MAIN'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'PersonID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
'Name': ["Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Don", "Don", "Don", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"],
'Label': ["REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL", "REL"],
'RuleID': [55, 55, 55, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10],
'RuleNumber': [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 234, 567, 999]})

df.loc[df.groupby('Name')['RuleNumber'].idxmin()[:], 'Label'] = 'MAIN'
```

Comment: It's better to pass the index values directly to `.loc`. It works, but there is no need to search for whether or not index values are there with `.isin`. You can essentially do `df.loc[indexes, 'Label'] = 'MAIN'` to remove that redundant step of searching with `isin`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `duplicated` on PersonID:

```
df.loc[~df['PersonID'].duplicated(),'Label'] = 'MAIN'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   PersonID Name Label  RuleID  RuleNumber
0         1  Jan  MAIN      55           3
1         1  Jan   REL      55           4
2         1  Jan   REL      55           5
3         2  Don  MAIN       3           1
4         2  Don   REL       3           2
5         2  Don   REL       3           3
6         3  Joe  MAIN      10         234
7         3  Joe   REL      10         567
8         3  Joe   REL      10         999
```